# Using an IF statement to concatenate a string and a number

Tags: if-statement, latex

I'm working with a LaTeX screenplay documentclass document that has a slide counter in a newcommand that I wrote"

```
\newcommand{\slide}[1]{
    \stepcounter{slidecounter}
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \underline{\textbf{Slide \arabic{slidecounter}}}
    \end{center}
    \rule{6in}{0.01in}
    \par    
    #1
}
```

This works perfectly for my purposes.  But now I'd like to modify it so that it is something like:

```
\newcommand{\slide}[1]{
    \stepcounter{slidecounter}
    \newpage
    \begin{center}
        \underline{\textbf{Slide \arabic{slidecounter}}}
    \end{center}
    \rule{6in}{0.01in}
        %%
    If slidecounter < 10 then "00" + slidecounter = ctr
    Else if slidecounter >= 10 & slidecounter < 100 then ctr = "0" + slidecounter
    Else ctr = slidecounter
        %%
    \par\bigskip
    \begin{center}
        \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.50]{"Page_"ctr.png}}
    \end{center}    
    \par    
    #1
}
```

The "Page_###.png" is a numbering scheme for identifying image files such as Page_010.png, Page_099.png, Page_109.png.

How do I write the If clause to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Walt Paczkowski

Answer (score 2):

If you add

```
\newcommand{\threedigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{#1}<100 0\fi
  \ifnum\value{#1}<10 0\fi
  \arabic{#1}%
}
```

to your preamble, you can use

```
\includegraphics[..]{Page_\threedigits{slidecounter}.png}
```

to have a 3-digit representation for you `slidecounter` counter.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I really appreciate the help.  By the way, can you clarify the "fi"?  What is it?

Comment: @Walt: `\fi` is the closure of every `\if...` statement. So you'll see `\ifnum <condition>  <true> \else <false> \fi`. There are other `\if`-statements in TeX as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to look up if-statements so I can use these more often. Thanks again.